# Rails: Unknown Attribute error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm going through the railstutorial.org book and getting Unknown attribute error in code

My User.rb file code is

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

 validates :name,presence:true,length: { maximum:50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email,presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness:{ :case_sensitive => false }
before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }



end
```

and my user_spec.rb file code is

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe User do
before do
@user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com" , password:"foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end
subject { @user }
it { should respond_to(:name) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }
it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
it {should respond_to(:password) }
it {should respond_to(:password_confirmation)}

it { should be_valid }
describe "when name is not present" do
before { @user.name = " " }
it { should_not be_valid }
end
describe "when name is too long" do
before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
it { should_not be_valid }
end
describe "when email format is invalid" do
it "should be invalid" do
addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
addresses.each do |invalid_address|
@user.email = invalid_address
@user.should_not be_valid
end
end
end
describe "when email format is valid" do
it "should be valid" do
addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
addresses.each do |valid_address|
@user.email = valid_address
@user.should be_valid
end
end
end
describe "when email address is already taken" do
before do
user_with_same_email = @user.dup
user_with_same_email.save
end
it { should_not be_valid }
end
describe "when email address is already taken" do
before do
user_with_same_email = @user.dup
user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
user_with_same_email.save
end
it { should_not be_valid }
end
describe "when password is not present" do
before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
it { should_not be_valid }
end
describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
it { should_not be_valid }
end

end
```

and what is going in terminal is

```
ritesh@ritesh-desktop:~/projects/sample_app$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3p327 :001 > User.create(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: nil)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: password
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3p327 :002 >
```

please give some clue how to run rectify this error!!

Comment: Add a password column to your users table? Or if you don't want to save passwords add `attr_accessor :password` to your model.

Comment: How to add a column i am just a beginner on this platform

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a column by generating a migration:

```
rails generate migration AddPasswordToUsers password:string
```

Then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

However, it looks like you're attempting to use `has_secure_password`, though you haven't added it to your User model. If this is the case, add the line `has_secure_password` to your User model and run this migration instead:

```
rails generate migration AddPasswordDigestToUsers password_digest:string
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same issue when working on a Ruby on Rails application with a PostgreSQL database in production.

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that I added some new columns to the table(s) in my **development environment** using migration files, but when I made a push to the **production environment**, I didn't create those new columns via migration.

All I had to do was to simply run a database migration in the **production environment**.

```
rails db:migrate
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**